# Executar função js Service Worker mesmo com o navegador fechado ou minimizado

Tags: javascript, pwa

Recentemente estou usando Service Worker, cheguei até consultar uns exemplos e a documentação que tem no google labs, porém confesso que estou com dificuldades para entender como eu posso **criar uma função no Service Worker , que deverá ser executada a cada 3 minutos mesmo se o usuário fechar o navegador ou se ele apenas minimizá-lo**.
Desde já eu agradeço se puderem me fornecer algumas orientações.

Meu cenário atual:
- Framework Php Laravel 5.5,
- php 7.0,
- jquery,
- Postgresql,
- bootstrap,
- servidor HTTPS
- já consegui instalar o serviço do service worker no navegador, o escopo dele eu configurei para pegar tudo que estiver dentro da raiz do site. O arquivo **sw.js** está localizado dentro da pasta public do Laravel.

Comment: Service Worker é um Proxy, ele executa funções durante a requisição e então encerra. As API's Web-Push e Sync podem operar em **"background"** mesmo que o usuário não esteja na aplicação más, é necessário que o navegador esteja "aberto" mesmo minimizado. Você pode usar `PostMessage` com uma lógica (função) de intervalos para lançar mensagens entre seu arquivo `js` e o Service Worker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Service Worker é um Proxy, ele executa funções durante a requisição e então encerra.

As API's **Web-Push** e **Sync** podem operar em **"background"** mesmo que o usuário não esteja na aplicação más, é necessário que o navegador esteja "aberto" mesmo minimizado.

Você pode usar `PostMessage` com uma lógica (função) de intervalos para lançar mensagens entre seu arquivo `js` e o Service Worker:

**sw.js**:

```
function ExecutaFuncao() {
    postMessage({
        cmd: 'response',
        data: 'um valor qualquer'
    })
}
// message handler
self.addEventListener('message', event => {
    if ( 'cmd' in event.data ) {
        let command = event.data.cmd
        switch (command) {
            case 'executa-funcao':
                ExecutaFuncao()
            break
        }
    }
})
// enviar mensagem do Service Worker
async function postMessage(data) {
    let clients = await self.clients.matchAll()
    clients.forEach(client => client.postMessage(data))
}
```

Você pode enviar parâmetros para funções definidas em seu Service Worker...ou simplesmente executar funções dependendo do "comando" enviado.

**main.js**

```
if ( 'serviceWorker' in navigator ) {
    // observe messages
    navigator.serviceWorker.addEventListener('message', event => {
        if ( 'cmd' in event.data ) {
            let command = event.data.cmd
            switch(command) {
                case 'response':
                    console.log('[ServiceWorker Response]: ', event.data.data)
                break
            }
        }
    })
    // simple lógic
    setInterval(() => {
        if ( navigator.serviceWorker.controller ) {
            navigator.serviceWorker.controller.postMessage({
                cmd: 'executa-funcao'
            })
        }
     }, 5000) // every 5 seconds

    // register
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('/sw.js', {
        scope: '/'
    }).then(register => {
        console.log('[Register ServiceWorker] We are live  !')
    }).catch(e => {
        console.warn('service worker failed', e)
    })
}
```

Comment: Legal @LauroMoraes, já deu para ter uma ideia de onde eu devo partir agora. Eu agradeço pela ajuda. Como funciona aqui no fórum, é só eu clicar na sua resposta como a resposta escolhida? Perdão, é minha primeira participação aqui rsrs.

Comment: Sim, é assim que funciona. Basta clicar no ícone `✔`, se aparecer uma outra resposta que você julgue "melhor" dentro do escopo de sua questão bastará mudar a escolha de resposta aceita sem problemas. Seja bem vindo a comunidade o/

Comment: Muito obrigado @LauroMoraes. Espero conseguir ajudar os outros também, da mesma forma que estou sendo ajudado. Um abraço.